# Как отредактировать текст сообщения отправленное ботом в телеграме? Python telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, async-await

Я пишу функцию, в которой будет имитация загрузки, делаю через `asyncio` используя `await`. Мне нужно обновлять сообщение каждую секудну, чтобы казалось что идет загрузка, но я не понимаю, почему компилятор ругается на `await` или на `edit_text`, пытался найти документацию про `edit_text`, но увы не нашел... Суть проблемы заключается в том, что выдает ошибку после отправки первого сообщения: `TypeError: object Message can't be used in 'await' expression`, помогите пожалуйста

```
async def func(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    msg = await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await msg.edit_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await msg.edit_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='️⬜️⬜️⬜️️')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await msg.edit_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='️⬜️️️')
```

Comment: Зачем вы все евейтите? Это же телебот, он синхронный бот

Comment: А синхронный бот может работать с несколькими пользователями? я читал, что асинхронность позволяет использовать бота нескольким юзерам независимо от другого, поправьте меня если я не прав

Comment: Ну там потоки есть, но все ещё синхронный. Рекомендую юзать aiogram

Comment: ох, с понятием потоков я слабо знаком пока что и aiogram тоже только начинаю познавать

Answer (score 0):

Может, попробовать использовать **bot.edit_message_text**?

```
async def func(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    msg = await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️')
    msg_id = msg.message_id

    
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️', message_id = msg_id)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='⬜️⬜️⬜️', message_id = msg_id)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='⬜️', message_id = msg_id)
```

Comment: теперь компилятор на await ругается в строках где написано `await bot.edit_message_text`, когда навожу на него то пишет `Cannot find reference await in Message | bool `, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: я попробовал убрать `await` там, где ошибка и теперь он возвращает ошибку, которую я описал в самом вопросе

Comment: в общем, разобрался, в вашем ответе нужно убрать `await` в строке `msg = await bot.send_message` и убрать еще пару `await` в строках `await bot.edit_message_text` и тогда все начнет работать как надо